# How to create a random number generator that is completely random.

Tags: number-theory, random

I'm trying to write an autonomous music composition program that makes use of many random number generators in order to make seemingly random melodies but I have no clue how to formulate a rigorous formula or algorithm to create actual random numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [Random.org](http://www.random.org).

Comment: Same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123073/is-there-a-formula-that-generates-a-completely-random-number?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  It is impossible.  There are however good libraries out there for pseudo-random number generation.

Here's a list of generators:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators

Is there a particular programming language you are using?

Comment: As of now, no. I'm probably going to go with java but right now I'm mainly just trying to get all of the mathematics for the music theory completed before I continue with programming. I don't know much about programming as of yet but I'm teaching myself the programming as I go.

Comment: That's awesome, sounds like a cool project and you'll learn a lot too.  For Java, there is a Random class specifically for generating pseudo-random numbers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no algorithm to generate truly random numbers. An algorithm follows rules (by definition), so its output can't be random.